# How to refer commit time of the records on BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Range decorators of BigQuery refers `added time` of the records.

> References table data added between  and

(from https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/table-decorators)

Or it seems to have been also called `commit time`.

> the timestamps are compared to a commit time

(from https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=160#c12)

Is there any way to know `added time` or `commit time` of the records?

Answer (score 0):

I.e. something like "SELECT ThisRowCommitTime(), * FROM table", or through Tabledata:list, that would expose the timestamp for each row?

No, that's a reasonable thing to look for, but it's not currently available.

You could [file a feature request](http://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/) and it might help there to motivate further about how the feature would be useful to you.  In particular: would this still be useful to you if it were exposed only for data up to 7 days old, matching the range you can time-travel with a decorator?